# What are the main diference between WAS Liberty Profile and WAS downloaded by Installation Manager

Tags: websphere-liberty

From developer viewpoint, what is diference between WebSphere  Application Server(1.5GB)  installed by Installation Manager and WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile (65 MB)? I will develop an application based on  EJB, JSF and JPA. According to my search, Liberty Profile is an easy way to start develop with Websphere. I would appreciate any comment because I am in charge of preparing the workstations for a team and it is my first time to heard about Liberty Profile. I guess that Liberty Profile must be a smaller Web Server similiar to Tomcat plus EJB support and without Console Administration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at this Redbook http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248076.html?Open particularly chapter 1 "An introduction to the Liberty profile" to learn more about Liberty Profile.

As for the programming models supported (which you can check on the same chapter), depending on the exact versions of EJB, JSF and JPA you need to work with, Liberty could, our could not be a fit for development. Also, in the same chapter you can read about the compatibility between Liberty Profile and the full Profile.

You can find also this post helpful https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/2013/05/20/alasdair_nottingham_talks_about_what_makes_liberty_different/

Answer (score 11):

The key difference between WAS Liberty and WAS Classic boil down to the following: **Java EE 7 support** and **Legacy app support**

- WebSphere Liberty *supports Java EE 7* as of 8.5.5.6, WAS classic does not. WAS 9.0 supports Java EE 7
- WAS Liberty does not support some of the older apps that have now been deprecated in the Java EE API such as JAX-RPC.
- If you inherited an old application that takes advantage of WebSphere specific extensions you're generally bound to WAS Classic
- Existing administrative and deployment scripts would not likely work on WAS Liberty
- Network Deployment support is not as robust in WAS Liberty

However, if you are doing a new app it isn't too bad and you can pay for support for it without having to redeploy to something new unlike Glassfish or WildFly.  There's a 2GB limit for production on the *organization* level, but you can have unlimited *development* instances.  From what I can tell this is based on the honor system.

The following article documents at a high level the differences
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/was-classic-or-was-liberty-how-to-choose/

The white paper also referenced by the article details each difference
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/documentation/ChoosingWASClassicorWASLiberty.pdf

Comment: [WAS Classic now supports Java EE 7](http://blog.rahmannet.net/2016/07/websphere-v9-traditional-now-java-ee-7.html).

Answer (score 5):

The WebSphere Application Server chief architect has a blog post entitled [Liberty Archive Install and Installation Manager](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/docs/liberty_archive_install_and_installation_manager1/) that compares the two approaches.

There is also a side-by-side comparison on page 9 of the [IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Packaging Highlights](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/topic/com.ibm.iea.was_v8/was/8.5.5.0/content/WAS855_Install-Packaging.pdf?dmuid=20130807101602792413,) document.